# Connect to a database - a script suggestion?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

```
<html><head><title>Library Books</title></head>
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr><th>Book</th><th>Year Published</th><th>Author</th></tr>
<?php
 // connect
 require_once('DB.php');
 $db = DB::connect("mysql://librarian:passw0rd@localhost/library");
 if (DB::iserror($db)) {
   die($db->getMessage(  ));
 }
 // issue the query
 $sql = "SELECT books.title,books.pub_year,authors.name
         FROM books, authors
         WHERE books.authorid=authors.authorid
         ORDER BY books.pub_year ASC";
 $q = $db->query($sql);
 if (DB::iserror($q)) {
   die($q->getMessage(  ));
 }
 // generate the table
 while ($q->fetchInto($row)) {
?>
<tr><td><?= $row[0] ?></td>
    <td><?= $row[1] ?></td>
    <td><?= $row[2] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
 }
?>
```

How should DB.php look like to make the script run?

That doesn't work:

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "***");
define ("DB_USER", "***");
define ("DB_PASSWORD", "***");
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what errors do you get ?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in xxx.php on line 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to implement a DB class and all of the methods your script is calling. From what you pasted, `connect`, `isError`, `getMessage`, `query`, and `fetchInto`. You don't really want to write your own DB wrapper.

It acctually looks like that code is trying to use the old [PEAR DB package](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.php).

Take a look at the [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.php) package. It is pretty nice.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at it - it's indeed PEAR DB.